# Как узнать позиции областей многострочного текста ?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть проблема в определении нахождения элемента(`<a/>`): определяю с помощью .offset(), но в некоторых случах, когда ссылка находится крайне справа и имеет 2 слова, то второе слово переносится и .offset().left определяется как 0, как узнать, откуда именно начинается ссылка?

вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/4Qbfs/

видно, что ссылки начинаются в одном месте, но из-за переноса результаты разные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, есть ли обертки на jQuery, но на чистом JavaScript есть функция [`element.getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects), которая в случае многострочных элементов вернет массив областей.

```
$(".result").append("left of a1: " + $(".a1")[0].getClientRects()[0].left);
$(".result").append("<br/>left of a2: " + $(".a2")[0].getClientRects()[0].left);
```

Живой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/4JJvE/

Comment: Спасибо, но нашел выход проще: обойтись без переносов))